# How to set goog.ui.Autocomplete minimum input to 0

Tags: javascript, google-closure-library

I would like the autocomplete to show the entire list when the input box gets focused (no input is given). Would also like the auto complete to match substrings without having to fiddle with private variables.

At the moment the code is:

```
autocomplete = goog.ui.ac.createSimpleAutoComplete(
  gsa.Game.gameData.teams, team2, false);
matcher=autocomplete.getMatcher();
matcher.useSimilar_=true
autocomplete.setMatcher(matcher);
```

Similar matches work but have to set a private variable for that (no getter or setter available).

The other one I have not been able to find out; how to show all data when no input is given (like a smart select input). So when the textbox receives focus it'll show all data since there is no filter text given. These are basic things that one would like to configure but can't find it in the API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create descendants of `goog.ui.ac.AutoComplete`, `goog.ui.ac.ArrayMatcher` and `goog.ui.ac.InputHandler`. Also you will directly create the instance of auto complete object instead of calling `goog.ui.ac.createSimpleAutoComplete`.

---

In `goog.ui.ac.AutoComplete` descendant you assign custom input handler and matcher.

```js
goog.provide('my.ui.ac.AutoComplete');

goog.require('goog.ui.ac.Renderer');
goog.require('my.ui.ac.ArrayMatcher');
goog.require('my.ui.ac.InputHandler');


my.ui.ac.AutoComplete = function(data, input, opt_multi, opt_useSimilar) {

    var renderer = new goog.ui.ac.Renderer();
    var matcher = new my.ui.ac.ArrayMatcher(data, !opt_useSimilar);
    var inputhandler = new my.ui.ac.InputHandler(null, null, !!opt_multi, 300);

    goog.ui.ac.AutoComplete.call(this, matcher, renderer, inputhandler);
    inputhandler.attachAutoComplete(this);
    inputhandler.attachInputs(input);
};
goog.inherits(my.ui.ac.AutoComplete, goog.ui.ac.AutoComplete);
```

---

In `goog.ui.ac.ArrayMatcher` descendant you need to override `getPrefixMatches()` method, since the default behaviour discards empty strings. So if there is an empty string, we just return the first x rows from the data.

```js
goog.provide('my.ui.ac.ArrayMatcher');

goog.require('goog.ui.ac.ArrayMatcher');


my.ui.ac.ArrayMatcher = function(rows, opt_noSimilar) {
    goog.ui.ac.ArrayMatcher.call(this, rows, opt_noSimilar);
};
goog.inherits(my.ui.ac.ArrayMatcher, goog.ui.ac.ArrayMatcher);


my.ui.ac.ArrayMatcher.prototype.getPrefixMatches = function(token, maxMatches) {        
    if (token == '')
    {
        // for empty search string, return first maxMatches rows
        return this.rows_.slice(0, maxMatches);
    }
    else
    {
        return goog.base(this, 'getPrefixMatches', token, maxMatches);
    }
};
```

---

In `goog.ui.ac.InputHandler` descendant you need to override `processFocus()` method, and force to show the autocomplete popup. This can be done by calling `update()` method with first parameter set to true.

```js
goog.provide('my.ui.ac.InputHandler');

goog.require('goog.ui.ac.InputHandler');


my.ui.ac.InputHandler = function(opt_separators, opt_literals, opt_multi, opt_throttleTime) {
    goog.ui.ac.InputHandler.call(this, opt_separators, opt_literals, opt_multi, opt_throttleTime);
};
goog.inherits(my.ui.ac.InputHandler, goog.ui.ac.InputHandler);


my.ui.ac.InputHandler.prototype.processFocus = function(target) {
    goog.base(this, 'processFocus', target);

    // force the autocomplete popup to show
    this.update(true);
};
```